# If $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} a_n r_n=0$, what can we say about $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} a_n (r_n)^2=0$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

If $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n r_n=0$ for every natural $N$ where $a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ and $r_n\in(0,1]$, can we conclude anything significant about $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n (r_n)^2,\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n (r_n)^3.. $?

EDIT: The related and completed question is in my new post here: ([Find constants $b_i$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n (\sum_{n=1}^{t} b_i[r_n-(r_n)^2]+s(i))=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060051/find-constants-b-i-such-that-sum-n-1n-a-n-sum-n-1t-b-ir-n-r-n))

Comment: If $\sum_{n=1}^{N}{a_nr_n}=0$ for every $N$, doesn't that mean $a_Nr_N=0$ for every $N$?

Comment: Yessssssssssss!

Comment: Thus, no question?

Comment: Please do not use `\displaystyle` in titles.

Comment: @Winther Thanks, I will be reviving my work and notebook first. I think there is something missing.